# Tranforming a Rectangle to an Ellipse in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I have a world map:

> [image: World Map Rectangle]

It is rectangular.

I want a world map that looks like this:

> [image: World Map Ellipse]

Now normally I would just use the second map, but I want to change the latitude the map is centered on. Because of the projection in the second map, moving continents left and right won't work properly, so I have to start working from the top map to make things look proper.

Once I've properly recentered my map, how can I use gimp to transform the rectangular shape in to the elliptical shape found below? Cage transform works on deforming rectangles, but it doesn't deform them to look like ellipses. Is there any way to accomplish this with GIMP?

Comment: In order to do this you may have to rotate your image through 90 degrees first.   
Menu > Filters > Distorts > Curve Bend

Answer (score 0):

According to http://xkcd.com/977/, it seems you want to reproject an equirectangular map with Robinson's proj.

Instead of messing around with gimp, [NASA's G.projector](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/gprojector/) can reproject an equirectangular map image to a lot of different projections, including Robinson's.